# Executing php file from another php file uses too much CPU

Tags: php, exec

I have read the other questions on SO with a similar title, but that's not what this question is about. I know HOW to execute a PHP script from another PHP script. The problem is, when I do so, it uses far too much CPU. I would like to know how to reduce this.

I have a simple front-controller-like script called index.php. It processes GET requests from a client and depending on the "action" parameter passed, it sends the request to the appropriate file to handle it. For example, this is a client request:

```
xhttp.open("GET", serverURL + "?action=doSomething" + "&userID=" + user.ID + "&time=" + lastServerTime, true);
```

index.php has an array that maps the "action" parameter to the appropriate file:

```
exec('php ' . $url_map[$action] . ' "' . $parameter1 . '"' . ' "' . $parameter2 . '" 2>&1', $output, $return_value);
```

For testing purposes, I have created a PHP script that does nothing except measure CPU utilisation and dump it to a log file:

```
<?php

function varDumpToFile($parameter1) {
    $file = 'log.txt';
    $dump = $parameter1;

    $output = print_r($dump, true);

    file_put_contents($file, $output, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

varDumpToFile(`ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args --no-headers| sort -t. -nk1,2 -k4,4 -r |head -n 5`);

?>
```

This produces a log file that looks like this:

```
9.0 3123052 user   /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php cputest.php 10 147424 1537625595
```

Clearly, a PHP script shouldn't take 9% of CPU to execute. For comparison, I've run the same script directly accessing it via a GET request:

```
0.1 3186198 user   lsphp:ic_html/dev/php/cputest.php
```

0.1% is more like it. But why does calling this PHP script from another PHP script use so much CPU? Is it because I have to execute a "new instance" of PHP when I exec PHP, which has a lot of overhead? If so, is there a way to exec a PHP script using an "already running" instance of PHP? Or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to shell out to execute the PHP files using the CLI? I've never seen anyone do this before, and it's a serious security risk. Unless you're doing a lot of input validation, someone is going to do nasty things to your site.

Comment: What is the reason to call it via exec? Why are you thinking about CPU usage?

Do you want to run that process faster?

What kind of work does the called script do?

If you need to offload work done in the exec() method from the HTTP request cycle, look at Message Queue Systems like RabbitMq, ZeroMq

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Rob: there is a very specific reason I want to do this - the called file must run in the background, while index.php must instantly respond to the HTML client. My understanding from reading a lot on SO was that calling the "background" PHP file was the only way to have both: instant response to the client without the index.php script "waiting" for the background script to conclude before it replied to the client (which can take minutes), while having the background script happily running in the background without bothering anyone.

Comment: mblaettermann: I don't have any specific reason to call it via exec except that's what I thought was the right thing to do. I am thinking about CPU usage because it limits the resources available to clients. At ~10% for each client, that's only 10 concurrent clients. I don't need the process to run faster (it executes in under 1ms), but it does need to use less CPU. Thanks for your other suggestions, but this is an already existing application with a large codebase which actually runs pretty well (apart from this issue). I'm not going to change the entire architecture to solve one problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always say "when in doubt, look at PHP source code". [In here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/321c0cc3493998f731f0666127c093eff4e119eb/ext/standard/exec.c#L96), for instance. While doing `exec`, you have to fork the process, create a new stream, read from the input buffer, etc.

And also, while PHP is a compiled language, for the newly forked process, you must run the opcode compiler to generate opcodes (instructions similar to Java bytecode) and then execute those. You can read all about it [here](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/117-PHP-compiler-performance.html). In the end you run the compiler twice, for each fork separately.

Is it worth 9% of your CPU? I have no idea. Maybe. Maybe not. Who knows.

"Better solution"? Upgrade to latest version of PHP. PHP 5.6 is not supported anymore and security updates will cease in 3 months. Even better solution - keep a normal object-oriented and maintainable code without using `exec`. IMO, it's okay to play around with `exec` like you are. But if it's your production code, I pray for the souls of those, who would maintain your code after you.

Comment: Thanks for that - I can see why that's such a resource drain. It's definitely not worth 9% of my CPU. As you can see from my above tests, 0.1% of CPU is what I'd expect (and desire). Upgrading to PHP 7 is definitely on my to do list, but I need to solve this problem first before I can do that. Besides, I don't think the latest version of PHP will give me the performance gains I need if my code isn't written correctly in the first place. Is there another, better way to run a PHP script in the background, called from an existing PHP script, while maintaining an instant response to the client?

Comment: Maybe you should reanalyze the purpose of what you are doing? It's hard to say without seeing the project as a whole... For instance, mblaettermann suggested an `amqp` system. Depending on the implementation, it would also create a new process though, but will allow to manage the queue and concurrent users will not just die. Or maybe you just need to redefine half the stuff you do. To give you a good solution, I'd have to see the code for myself ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks Alex. I marked your answer as correct as it does answer my question as to why exec'ing a new PHP file would take so much CPU (when I don't want it to). My solution which I'm currently testing is to replace exec in my front controller with include_once. From initial testing, it definitely gets the CPU utilisation back down to the 0.1% mark. Whether it also allows me to run a PHP script in the background, I'm not sure. If it doesn't, then I'll definitely take a look at the alternative approaches suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever which way you run your application be `mod_php` or `fpm`, they rely on having worker processes ready to manage your request. Process management is built in: they will do their best to keep as many workers idle as you specify and reuse them to avoid exactly this problem, having to fork processes at the least desirable moment.

Not only there's overhead on executing new processes, but the execution environment will be completely different too. If you look into your php configuration there will be several `php.ini` files, one for each specific environment. This means that one environment could have different modules enabled or different configuration outright. It's not uncommon to have cli scripts `max_execution_time` or `memory_limit` set to unlimited. This can affect resource usage on your server, but it's also a pain to maintain.

Also, since your scripts will be running in a brand new process in a different execution environment, this won't have access to some variables (like `$_SERVER` or `$_POST`) or capabilities like sending headers.

And there's this thing called shared memory. As @Alex mentions, scripts have to be compiled. If you have opcode cache enabled (which you should) the bytecode gets cached when compiled and this compilation process can be skipped if the resulting bytecode it's there already. For this to work you *need* to have a persistent running process that can keep this memory around. If you are creating a new process it can't access this shared area and has to do the compilation all by itself.

Comment: Good points about the execution environment and shared memory. Whilst I don't rely on those global variables for what I do, I may need to in future, so I can see why forking a new PHP process is undesirable. My max_execution_time and memory_limit is set pretty low, so there isn't a scenario where I get timeouts or run out of memory. As I asked Alex, is there another, better way to run a PHP script in the background, called from an existing PHP script, while maintaining an instant response to the client?